# Why is the directory listing different between Filezilla and Putty?

Tags: bash, putty, ls, filezilla

Help I'm new to bash
So I log into my hosting account ftp at Godaddy with Filezilla and my directory structure is this:

```
..
access (directory)
cgi (directory)
js (directory)
kml (directory)
stats (directory)
test (directory)
(and a bunch of files)
```

then I log in with Putty and from the -bash-3.25$ prompt ls:

```
data  error logs  htconfig  html  site  tmp
```

The home directory is `/var/chroot/home/content/48/10443756`

Can someone explain why these are different?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the reason must be: **you are listing different directories (or on different hosts)**

execute `pwd` on both (ssh & ftp) you will see difference

Comment: Also, FTP may be exposing a different directory structure than you get with a login shell. I've got the ftp root on my server as `/var/ftp`, not the true `/`. So even if `pwd` shows the same path, it may actually be a different directory.